# Response from Node server to Angular client undefined first time (only) specific request is made

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am having an issue where my Angular front end is getting back an ‘undefined’ response object from my Node server.

For starters the user makes a GET request for a restaurant name, the server returns an array of possible names.  When a name is clicked, and a unique id is used to make another GET request for more info from the server.  It is the first time that the second GET request is made where the issue arises.

The response object is defined and looks fine (as I have console.logged it at every step of the way) until is gets back to the getLocationResults function in services.js, where it is suddenly undefined.

So getLocationResults in services.js:

```
  var getLocationResults = function(id){
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/location/' + id
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('Error in services: ', err, 'config(req): ', err.config);
         //logs “Error in services: Object {data: null, status: -1, config:
         //Object, statusText: ""} “
    })
    .then(function(resp){
      console.log('Response in getLocationResults: ', resp)
    //logs “Response in getLocationResults:  undefined”
      return resp.data;
    })
  };
```

makes an $http request to the server through this route:

```
router.get('/location/:id', function(req, res){
  var results = Results.findByLocationId(req.params.id)
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('Response IN API: =========', response);
    res.send(response);
  })
});
```

to this model, which queries an external API:

```
Results.findByLocationId = function(id){
  var baseUrl =  'https://data.austintexas.gov/resource/nguv-n54k.json?  
  facility_id=' + id
  var options = {
    url: baseUrl,
    'X-App-Token': appToken
  };
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request.get(options,
    function(error, response, body){
      if(error) {
        console.log("Error!", error);
        return error
      } else {
        response.body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('LOCATION response-body-length: ', response.body.length)
        resolve(response.body);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The response is fine on the server side, but somehow gets dropped in between get.(‘/location’, function(req, res){ …}) in my routes and getLocationResults in services.js.  The res.send(response) function works without fail in the other routes, so I am assuming it is ok to use here.

One of the odd parts is that after I get this error, if I try to make a request for this facility_id or search again for another, the request comes through like it should.  I have no idea why this error would get thrown only on the first time I make request.

The second odd part is that there is nothing different about the server side model or routing for this request than the previous request that must first be made to search for either zip code results or restaurant name results.  This is what getNameResults looks like in my services file:

```
 var getNameResults = function(name){
   return $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/api/name/' + name
    })
    .catch(function(err){
  console.log('Error in services: ', err)
})
.then(function(resp){
  return resp.data
 });
};
```

Any ideas why my first response back to getLocationResults is undefined, but then is fine on the next request/response? Thanks!

EDIT (for inclusion of XHR logging):

When GET request that results in error is made this logs in the console:

```
angular.js:11756 
XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/api/location/10835756".
v
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11756
sendReq @ angular.js:11517
serverRequest @ angular.js:11227
processQueue @ angular.js:15961
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15977
Scope.$eval @ angular.js:17229
Scope.$digest @ angular.js:17045
Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17337
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25023
defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3456
eventHandler @ angular.js:3444
```

And then in Chrome Dev tools, under Network tab with XHR selected:

The only request that is present is one to search.html, which is my home page and .otherwise route in Angular.  Here is the log:

[image: XHR]

The Response tab just says "failed to load response".

error.config: Object {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array[1],
    transformResponse:Array[1], url: "/api/location/10835756", headers: Object}

Is it possible that I am using $location.path incorrectly in my searchCtrl?

```
  this.findByLocationId = function(id){
    console.log('ResultsCtrl in findByLocationId: ', id)
    $routeParams.id = id;
    Search.getLocationResults(id)
    .then(function(inspections){
      console.log('Funky Cold Medina') // doesn't log
      ResultService.inspections = inspections;

    })
    .then(function(){
      $location.path('/location');
    })
  }
```

Comment: Just saying, you should not `return error` but rather `reject(error)` in that callback

Comment: When the error is logged in `.catch(function(err){ console.log('Error in services: ', err, 'config(req): ', err.config); })`, then that error handler *does* return `undefined` which is the value you are receiving further down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from your server is where the undefined comes from you need post the exact Response as received by Chrome when the error happens so that we can see what is happening there.

In chrome Dev tools enable XHR logging and when you see the failed request, drill down on it by clicking on the entry and again under the network tab.

You will see the exact conversation here that the browser had, make sure under the response tab that that your server isn't throwing anything funny. Also post it for us to analyse.

[image]

Comment: I think I have added all that you mentioned (and now have the XHR logger in my toolbelt, thank you for that).  I am not sure why this error is causing the search.html view to load.  The url is 'http://localhost:8080/location#/' after the error.

Comment: thanx for the additional info, could you please post the contents of the Response tab, or click source llink next to Response Headers

Comment: Done!  The contents of the response is the html for the search view (contained within search.html).

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct Response? earlier in your message the endpoint was: http://localhost:8080/api/location/10835756
But from your XHR request I can see clearly the request is to: http://localhost:8080/views/search.html
Also are we not expecting JSON data from the webservice for your Angular app because you are doing JSON.parse(body);

Comment: Also the $http method expects JSON or Object data. If you want to parse different data then you need to overwrite the transformResponse method of $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Could you please update your Response info with the http://localhost:8080/api/location/10835756 endpoint

Comment: Added the correct XHR log, the Response tab is empty and just says "Failed to Load Response".

Comment: Ok so we know there is no response from the server. What web server are you using.? Have u got the the correct rewrite rules going for that url?  Can u look at the logs and also try and enable error display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112306/discussion-between-swoopedj-and-johan).